# How to compare date(between certain range) in mysql if I have one date column in 'd-m-Y' format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have write this code but not get proper record.

1.

```
SELECT first_name,date 
from user where date between  '01-05-2012' and '05-05-2012'
```

2.

```
SELECT first_name,date from user 
where date >= '01-05-2012' date <= '05-05-2012'
```

What is the problem in above code? What will be the write query?

Here is Sample data

```
first_name  date
Sonu    23-01-2012
Saqib   20-02-2012
Sachin  01-04-2012
Ankit   17-08-2012
Michal  12-13-2011
```

Comment: a "date" column with a "format" is a contradiction in terms (a date is only "formatted" when you display it, not when you store id). Do you by chance store your date in a `varchar` column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your date first using `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d-%m-%Y') 
      BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-12-05'
```

This will select dates starting from `June 01 2012` until `December 05 2012`

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/777be/6)

if you really want to stick with your format,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d-%m-%Y') 
      BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('01-05-2012','%d-%m-%Y') AND 
              STR_TO_DATE('05-12-2012','%d-%m-%Y')
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/777be/7)

Comment: Did you see the result? `Ankit | 17-08-2012`. Month is `05` while the condition is `BETWEEN '2012-05-01' AND '2012-12-05'`

Comment: `'2012-12-05'` is in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.So what's the problem?

Comment: Okay got it. Actually OP's query and given values will never give any value.

Comment: in the OPs example, he is finding between `June 01 2012` and `June 05 2012`, but it will not have result that's why i changed it to `December 05, 2012`.  :D

Comment: Hey John my problem is solved after your answer, thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your dates must be specified in ISO format (yyyy-mm-dd):

```
SELECT first_name,date from user 
where date >= '2012-05-01' and date <= '2012-05-05'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I can not change my whole db and I have to do in 'd-m-Y' format .Is there any solution for good result?

Comment: Ah, ok, I answered before there was sample data, my apologies. In this case I would do as in the other answers, use STR_TO_DATE().

Answer (score 0):

if the date/time format matches the supported format, MySQL performs implicit conversion to convert the value to a `DATETIME`

If you want to explicitly convert the string to a DATETIME, the [STR_TO_DATE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) would be the best choice

Answer (score 0):

If your date column's data type is date
Use `DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')` otherwise

```
STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d'))
```